# jQuery - Trouble with children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container with several divs inside of it. Only one of the divs should should at a time. The container is essentially just a jQuery slider of divs. It should show and hide the next/prev div depending on which button you click, but it returns an error on the following line:

```
children[current--].show();
```

I'm not sure as to why this is happening. I am calling children (an array) then trying to access the index with an int--, then showing it, but it never shows.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n6fW7/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
    <div id="prev" class="arrow">></div>
    <div id="next" class="arrow"><</div>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('#content').append('<div class="box"><p class="title">1</p><p class="text">abc</p></div><div class="box"><p class="title">2</p><p class="text">efg</p></div>');

    var children = $('#content').find('.box');
    var count = children.length;
    var current = 1;
    $('.box').not(children[0]).hide();

    $('.arrow').click(function(){
        var where = $(this).attr('id');
        if(where == 'next'){
            if(current != count){
                current++;
            }
        }
        else{
            // previous
            if(current > 2){
                current--;
            }
        }
        $('.box').hide();
        children[current--].show();
    });
});
```

Comment: `children[current--]` is just a bad idea. do this instead `children[current]` followed by `current--;` on the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the indexer in a jQuery object returns the raw DOM element, which does not contain the `show()` function. You can use the `eq()` function instead of the indexer, which returns a jQuery object wrapping the DOM element:

```
children.eq(current--).show();
```

Comment: That was the problem! Great explanation, I should have realized it was element. I will accept your answer when the time limit is up.