# JQuery, html() on a table cell returns "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been having some problems with JQuery.

I have a HTML table with the names having the class .ulName
When I retrieve them with $('.ulName'), I have no problem. When I iterate over them with alert(), Chrome tells me they are indeed HTMLTableCellElement. But when I use the html() method on them, I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". I tried to use other methods to see how it would work (append() for example) but it did the same thing.

I also tried to change from a forloop to $.each but it did the same thing.

And finally, I also tried $.parseHTML but it returns null.

Here is the code source, I hope you can help me with my problem because I don't see why it wouldn't work. Thank you in advance for your answers.

```
$('#ulFilter').on('input', function () {
    var uploads = $('.ulName');

    for (var i=0; i < uploads.length; i++) {
        alert(uploads[i].html());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the indexer gets the raw DOM element, not the jQuery object. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532034/jquery-trouble-with-children/23532092#23532092).

The raw element does not have a function called `html`, but instead a property called `innerHTML`.

Here are a few solutions:

- using `uploads.eq(i)` instead of `uploads[i]`
- using `$(uploads[i])` instead of `uploads[i]`
- using `uploads[i].innerHTML` instead of `uploads[i].html()`

Comment: To simplify the for loop, you can use $.each with $(this) inside the function to make it simple

Comment: Similarly, you may also have used the standard innerHTML property instead of jQuery's html() function. (edit: as Stefano just said as well, so +1)

Answer (score 2):

$(".ulName") returns you a NodeList.

So you can use,

```
var uploads = $(".ulName");
$.each(uploads, function() {
    $(this).html();
});
```

Comment: It actually returns a jQuery object.